# How to efficiently utilize celery to execute multiple tasks under 1 second?

Tags: python, django, celery, digital-ocean, celerybeat

I am working on a web application which is hosted on a "DigitalOcean" server:

- 4GB RAM
- 2 vCPUs
- 25GB SSD

I have 20+ tasks. Each task takes 0.2 to 1 second. I want all these 20+ tasks to execute parallelly i.e, they must all complete execution under 1 second.

I am using celery to execute these tasks periodically every 1 second(24/7). The application is designed such if a task is not executed under 1 second from its previous execution, the task is removed. (Another task `task_remover` checks regularly and removes tasks.)

I'm using `eventlet` and 2 workers with `-c 20`.

So, I start with 20+ tasks to be executed every second under 1 second. This runs for a while. But after a few hours, all tasks are being removed(not at once).

So, my questions with the above server configuration are:

- Are these tasks actually executed in parallel?
- 0.2*20 tasks = 4.0 seconds/2 vCPUs = 2.0 seconds for the completion of all tasks? Correct me?
- Should I continue with `eventlet` or use `prefork`?
- Should I go for parallelism or concurrency? how?
- If you suggest parallelism: How many workers should I run? And is it ok if I use `--concurrency 20`? Or should I go with `--concurrency 2`, with 2 being the number of vCPUs?
- If you suggest concurrency:  How many workers should I run? `--concurrency ??`?
- What configuration would you recommend? How many vCPUs and How much RAM?

The target: I need these 20+ tasks running 24/7 and shouldn't give `task_remover`(as mentioned above) a chance to remove these tasks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you've implemented your custom logic to revoke expired tasks instead of using the built-in option (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#expiration)? Having another task checking for expired tasks sounds tricky to synchronise

Regarding the execution time, doesn't it really depends on what the task is doing? I mean, if for example you do a HTTP call in your task, how can you guarantee a max duration for that task?

Comment: Sorry, linked the wrong page. This is the time limit option I meant: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#time-limits

Comment: @fabio.sussetto Just for the purpose of understanding, I said that there is a `task_remover`. But actually, the task itself runs on such condition=> if last_time < 1 sec: execute. I have tested using the `time_limit` and `soft_time_limit` option too. But of no help. I'm doubting it to be load on the processors and the tasks being queued. But the CPU usage never touches beyond 80%. anything else?

Comment: Hi, any news here? :)